# Hyperledger Fabric: Can a smart contract secretly add numbers and only share the sum?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, ethereum, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

Scenario:

I have 4 nodes in which each node sends a number. Each number should not be visible to any node other than the owner. The smart contract should secretly add all 4 numbers without viewing them to any member. Only the result which is the summation should be visible to all contracts.

Is the above scenario possible when using hyperledger fabric?

Answer (score 2):

The asymmetric encryption maybe the way to do it. The nodes use the public key to encrypt their number. And only smart contract have the key to decrypt it. You somehow need to dig deep inside the API see how the contract interact with the CA server.

Comment: Lets say that numbers are encrypted so users can't view the numbers. But, the smart contract has access to decryption keys which is a must in order to add the numbers. Knowing that the smart contract is replicated to all peers and it is stored locally. So, users have access to smart contracts which by its turn has access to decryption keys. Thus, users can obtain the decryption keys by tampering the machine. If this is the case then it is not completely secure. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

**You can easily achieve this by using Symmetric encryption like AES.**

- Data(number) that you are using can be encrypted using AES. what you will get as output will be IV, password, tag and encrypted data. You can store encrypted data on blockchain for everyone to see. However, only those entities that wish to see the decrypted data can ask the owner of data for the required 3 keys(IV, password, tag) which will not be stored in the blockchain.